# face Uncaught Syntax Error when check (add try-catch wrapping)

Tags: syntax-error

i face this error
[The error I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2XRz.png) 
here the file : https://igrafix.ir/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/autoptimize_c709febde8a57bd03504ae5fe6f38a57.php

when this [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7aTO.png) in photo Be checked above error happening. (site performance Improves 60%) But I encountered some problems ! like (Header menu doesn't load)

i tried : de active all plugins but doesn't work !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding this Excluded JavaScript Code

```
/jquery-?[0-9.](.*)(.min|.slim|.slim.min)?.js
```